# Accessing an outlet in another class (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, class

I am trying to access an outlet, an imageView, which is in another class.  When I type the outlet name, it generates an error, for the outlet is in another class.  How do I access an imageView outlet in another class?

Code:

```
//Class I am trying to call the outlet in
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()       
    if photosAsset == nil {

        //ERROR: Use of unresolved identifier: myImageView, since myImageView is in the class PhotoThumbnail
        myImageView.image = ""
    }



//Class with the oulet 
class PhotoThumbnail: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var myImageView : UIImageView!

}
```

Comment: You need a reference to the `PhotoThumbnail` object instance and then you can say something like `thumbnail.myImageView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a PhotoThumbnail object

var photoThumbnail = PhotoThumbnail() // Without any initializers

then

photoThumbnail.image

Since it is collectionViewCell, do it in cellforItemAtIndexPath Method